# html dropdown form post to php

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a strange error with my form. I always get a Daily selection with a date of 01 Jan 2000. The code for the form is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="mainForm" action="ReportForm.php" method="post">
      How Often to Generate Report: 
      <select id="period" onchange="Change(this);">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">Daily</option>
        <option value="1">Weekly</option>
        <option value="2">Monthly</option>
      </select>

      <br />

      <input type="submit" title="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are 3 more dropdowns like this for month, day, and year. I might have guessed that the selected="selected" had something to do with it, but the year 2000 is not an option. The default values for theses are January, 1, and 2012. I am thoroughly confused by this, and would appreciate any help.

The PHP associated with this is:

```
<?php
  require "Search.php";
  require "Schedule.php";

  Schedule( $_POST['period'],
                  mktime(23, 59, 59, $_POST['month'],
                         $_POST['day'], $_POST['year']) );

  Search( "param1", "param2", "param3", "test@testing.com" );

  exit();
?>
```

Thanks,

-rusty

Comment: Your code doesn't show inputs for 'month', 'day' or 'year'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Form elements require a `NAME` attribute in order to be posted. You have an `ID` instead.

Comment: Sounds like this is the answer. The date you're getting is probably the result of one or more of your dynamic mktime parameters being blank.

Comment: Well, credit lack of knowledge for my mistake... Thanks very much. If I could, I'd upvote, but I'm new here

Comment: You're welcome. That's what the site is here for. Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyeballs.